# IRC over SSL on Weechat gives "error: An unexpected TLS packet was received."

Tags: tls, irc, weechat

So I'm trying to see up SSL for IRC through [**weechat**](http://weechat.org), but have been having issues.

I've generated a `.pem` file for my nick and also have installed the `ca-bundle.crt`, but keep getting a TLS handshake error.

```
15:39:14 freenode  ℹ  ╡ irc: connecting to server chat.freenode.net/6667 (SSL)...
15:39:14 freenode =!= ╡ irc: TLS handshake failed
15:39:14 freenode =!= ╡ irc: error: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
15:39:14 freenode  ℹ  ╡ irc: reconnecting to server in 10 seconds
```

I've been reading the docs [**here**](https://weechat.org/files/doc/weechat_faq.en.html#irc_ssl_connection), appear to have all my settings right, and have a valid `pem` file, but I'm not sure what could be the issue.

```
weechat.network.gnutls_ca_file            string   "/usr/local/opt/curl-ca-bundle/share/ca-bundle.crt"
irc.server.freenode.ssl              boolean  on
irc.server.freenode.ssl_cert         string   "%h/ssl/nick.pem"
irc.server.freenode.ssl_priorities  string   "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS-ALL:+VERS-TLS1.0:+VERS-SSL3.0:%COMPAT"
```

Any ideas? Any tips or ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
15:39:14 freenode  ℹ  ╡ irc: connecting to server chat.freenode.net/6667 (SSL)...
```

Weechat defaults to port 6667 if you don't specify. Freenode uses 66**9**7.

```
/set irc.server.freenode.addresses irc.freenode.net/6697
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question but it is shown in the top results on Google.

What fixes this error, quite a lot of times, is playing with `irc.server.servername.ssl_dhkey_size`. Some servers accept `512`, some `1024`. try powers of two and see if one works.

I would also appreciate it somebody could enlighten why this is actually working.

Answer (score 0):

In Debian 9, this worked for me...

```
apt-get install ca-cacert
```

Then in weechat I did

```
/server add freenode chat.freenode.net/7070 -ssl
/connect freenode
```

If that doesn't work, I'm guessing you might want to...

```
apt-get upgrade openssl
```